# Gazebo can't startup occasionally with 'undefined symbol: _ZN3ros13isInitializedEv'?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I startup the gazebo8 by roslaunch and use with my own GUI plugin. But the gazebo can't startup occasionally with the output:

`gzclient: symbol lookup error: /home/xxx/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libxxxplugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros13isInitializedEv`

I am sure that the plugin is loaded. What is the reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19942/gazebo-can%27t-startup-occasionally-with-%27undefined-symbol:-_zn3ros13isinitializedev%27-?/) by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Add `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` in `target_link_libraries` may help.

---

Originally posted by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) with karma: 38 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0